# Set validation to check two dates with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time, datejs

I am trying to find the difference between two dates,when the user wants to change arrival date, remember the number of days between arrival/departure before the change , after changing arrival date , automatically set departure date to be x days after arrival date ,

So, if i have 01JUN17 - 05JUN17 (4days) and the user changes the arrival date to 04JUN17 then set departure to 08JUN17 (+4 days)

```js
function changedDate() {

    var startDate = $("#Arrival").val().split("-");
    var endDate = $("#Departure").val().split("-");   
    var arrivalDate = new Date(startDate[2], startDate[1] - 1, startDate[0]);
    var departureDate = new Date(endDate[2], endDate[1] - 1, endDate[0]);
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(departureDate.getDate() - arrivalDate.getDate());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

     
    if (arrivalDate >= departureDate) {
        var arrDate = arrivalDate;
        arrDate.setDate(arrDate.getDate() + 1);

        var month = arrDate.getMonth() + 1;
        if (month < 10)
            month = '0' + month;
        var day = arrDate.getDate();
        if (day < 10)
            day = '0' + day;
        var year = arrDate.getFullYear();

      
        $("#Departure").val(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);
    }         

    if (timeDiff > 1) {
        var arrDate = arrivalDate;
        var depDate = departureDate;
        arrDate.setDate(arrDate.getDate());
        depDate.setDate(depDate.getDate() + diffDays);

        var month = arrDate.getMonth() + 1;
        if (month < 10)
            month = '0' + month;
        var day = arrDate.getDate();
        if (day < 10)
            day = '0' + day;
        var year = arrDate.getFullYear();
        
        var monthd = depDate.getMonth() + 1;
        if (monthd < 10)
            monthd = '0' + month;
        var dayd = depDate.getDate();
        if (dayd < 10)
            dayd = '0' + day;
        var yeard = depDate.getFullYear();

        $("#Arrival").val(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);
        $("#Departure").val(dayd + '-' + monthd + '-' + yeard);
    }

    if(arrivalDate < departureDate) {
        var arrDate = arrivalDate;
        arrDate.setDate(arrDate.getDate() + 1);

        var month = arrDate.getMonth() + 1;
        if (month < 10)
            month = '0' + month;
        var day = arrDate.getDate();
        if (day < 10)
            day = '0' + day;
        var year = arrDate.getFullYear();

        $("#Departure").val(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);

    }
             
}
```

> this condition not related with the validation that i want this is to 
>   set departureDate +1 after arrival date on change

if (arrivalDate >= departureDate)

> this condition not related with the validation that i want this is to 
>   set departureDate +1 after arrival date on change

if(arrivalDate < departureDate)

> this condition i make it for this validation but didn't work

if (timeDiff > 1)

Comment: be careful that `getDate()` gives the day number in the month, which can lead to wrong `timeDiff` if days are in different months. You should try other functions, or even convert to timestamps before calculating intervals. by the way, what does it show when you log `timeDiff`?

Comment: `timeDiff` is wrong right like what you say gives me the day number in the month, what can should i use ??

Comment: For *diffDays* you should apply *Math.round* to the result as not all days are 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `getDate()` method to calculate the `timeDiff`, use `getTime()` and do a simple subtraction, followed by a *millisecond-to-days* refactoring.

Something like this:

```
var startDate = $("#Arrival").val().split("-");
var endDate = $("#Departure").val().split("-");   
var arrivalDate = new Date(startDate[2], startDate[1] - 1, startDate[0]);
var departureDate = new Date(endDate[2], endDate[1] - 1, endDate[0]);
var timeDiff = Math.abs(departureDate.getTime() - arrivalDate.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

Additionally, while subtracting Date type values, the `getTime()` method becomes optional and a direct subtraction `departureDate - arrivalDate` can also be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [datejs](http://datejs.com), creating a **TimeSpan** will help here.

```
var sync = function () {
    var val1 = $("#Arrival").val();
    var val2 = $("#Departure").val();

    var startDate = Date.parseExact(val1, "ddMMMyy");
    var endDate = Date.parseExact(val2, "ddMMMyy");

    var diff = new TimeSpan(endDate - startDate);
    var newEndDate = startDate.add(diff.days).days();

    $("#Departure").val(newEndDate.toString("ddMMyyy"));
};
```

You could trigger this function to automatically fire by wiring up a change listener on the startDate input field. Just a thought.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure date.js is a good recommendation, given that it has some bugs and hasn't been maintained in nearly 10 years.

Comment: The user tagged datejs in the original post.

Comment: @geoffrey.mcgill Thanks ,but `TimeSpan` Error can not defined ,not-working, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to remember either the arrival date before it was modified, or the number of days between arrival and departure dates. That way you can adjust the departure date by whatever amount the arrival date moved by.

You can store the "old" arrival date in lots of places, the *defaultValue* might be a good place. So when arrival date is updated, compare the new arrival date to the old one, set the old do the new one and adjust the departure date accordingly, e.g.

```js
// Some helper functions
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

function formatDate(date) {
  if (isNaN(date)) return date.toString();
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n}
  return z(date.getDate()) + '-' +
         z(date.getMonth()+1) + '-' +
         date.getFullYear();
}

function arrivalChange() {
  // Check value entered is valid, if so, 
  // make sure formatted correctly
  var arrDate = parseDMY(this.value);

  // Deal with invalid input
  if (isNaN(arrDate)) {
    this.value = "Invalid date";
    this.focus();
    return;
  }

  // Tidy formatting
  this.value = formatDate(arrDate);
  var daysDiff, depDate;
  var depEl = this.form.departureDate;
  
  // Get number of days shifted and move departure date accordingly
  daysDiff = Math.round((arrDate - parseDMY(this.defaultValue)) / 8.64e7);
  this.defaultValue = this.value;
  depDate = parseDMY(this.form.departureDate.defaultValue);
  depDate.setDate(depDate.getDate() + daysDiff);
  this.form.departureDate.value = formatDate(depDate);
  this.form.departureDate.defaultValue = formatDate(depDate);

}

function departureChange(){
  // Check value entered is valid, if so, 
  // make sure formatted correctly
  var depDate = parseDMY(this.value);
  if (isNaN(depDate)) {
    this.value = 'Invalid date';
    this.focus();
  } else {
    this.value = formatDate(depDate);
    this.defaultValue = formatDate(depDate);
   }
}

// Set dates in inputs, attach listeners
window.onload = function() {
  var form = document.forms[0];
  var now = new Date();
  form.arrivalDate.value = formatDate(now);
  form.arrivalDate.defaultValue = form.arrivalDate.value;
  now.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
  form.departureDate.value = formatDate(now);
  form.departureDate.defaultValue = form.departureDate.value;
  
  form.arrivalDate.addEventListener('change', arrivalChange, false);
form.departureDate.addEventListener('change', departureChange, false);
};
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  Arrival date (dd-mm-yyy): <input name="arrivalDate"><br>
  Departure  date (dd-mm-yyy): <input name="departureDate"><br>
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

If the user enters an invalid date at any time, pressing reset should get back the previous values.